# How to model the kinetics of a reaction while its not being stirred in a batch reactor?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, chemical-engineering, heat

lets consider the following reaction:
$$ A + B \rightarrow C $$
Where the rate of reaction ($r$) can be expressed as:
$$ r = k*c_a*c_b $$
Where $c_i$ is the concentration of species $i$ and $k$ is the reaction rate constant.

Hence the change in concentration of species A in a stirred-tank reactor (STR) is described as:
$$ \frac{dc_a}{dt}=-r $$

But that is in the case of it being stirred, how would you model a batch reactor not stirred? Is it just a change in the reaction rate constant?

Thanks, for your time!

Comment: Do the components mix when added to the reactor or do they separate to form two distinct layers?

Comment: @SolarMike Lets say its a liquid homogeneous mixture reacting with solid particles. If I don't get an answer here I might try in Chem stack, thanks!